# Search/sort/create functionality, implements bubblesort and sequential search

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, regex, homework

I've moved my `main()` to the bottom of the code block in order to fit it all in one class for this submission.  Is there a better way to do it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by Travis on 2/2/2015.
 */
public class CompanyEmployee {
    //Strings
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String eMail;
    private String birthDay;
    private String phoneNumber;

    //arraylist for CompanyEmployee objects
    static ArrayList<CompanyEmployee> employees = new ArrayList<CompanyEmployee>();

    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //email format
    String regex = "^(.+)@(.+).(.+)$";
    //Phone #
    String regex1 = "^\\(?([0-9]{3})\\)?[-.\\s]?([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]{4})$";
    //Uppercase/Lowercase
    String regex2 = "^[a-zA-Z]+$";
    //date format
    String regex3 = "^(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}/[0-3]?[0-9]/[0-3]?[0-9]$";

    //Patterns using specific regex's.
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);
    Pattern pattern3 = Pattern.compile(regex3);

    //default constructor, currently unused
    public CompanyEmployee() throws InvalidEmployeeBirthday, InvalidEmployeeEmail, InvalidEmployeeName, InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber {
        this.firstName = "";
        this.lastName = "";
        this.eMail = "";
        this.birthDay = "1901/01/01";
        this.phoneNumber = "000-000-0000";
    }

    /**
     * constructor to create employees using firstname, lastname, birthday, email, and phonenumber
     * Also throws several custom errors in based on regex values
     */
    public CompanyEmployee(String firstName, String lastName, String eMail, String birthDay, String phoneNumber) throws InvalidEmployeeName,
            InvalidEmployeeEmail, InvalidEmployeeBirthday, InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber {

        //Matcher for first name
        Matcher matcher = pattern2.matcher(firstName);
        //Matcher for last name
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern2.matcher(lastName);
        //Matcher for email
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(eMail);
        //Matcher for birthday
        Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(birthDay);
        //Matcher for phone number
        Matcher matcher4 = pattern1.matcher(phoneNumber);

        //if input passes regex, sets string firstName to string fn
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
        }

        //if input passes regex, sets string lastName to string ln
        if (matcher1.matches()) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
        }

        //if input passes regex, sets string eMail to string em
        if (matcher2.matches()) {
            this.eMail = eMail;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeEmail("Please use only a valid email addresses");
        }

        //if input passes regex, sets string birthDay to string b
        if (matcher3.matches()) {
            this.birthDay = birthDay;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeBirthday("Please only use dates in the format of 'yyyy/dd/mm'");
        }

        //if input passes regex, sets string phoneNumber to string pn
        if (matcher4.matches()) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber("Please use only use phone #'s in the format of " +
                    "American phone numbers: 123-456-7890");
        }
    }

    //creates a toString for the employee object.
    public String toString() {
        return "\nName: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\nEmail: " + eMail + "\nBirthday: " +
                "" + birthDay + "\nPhone #: " + phoneNumber + "\n";
    }

    //Create employees array
    public static void createArray() {

        CompanyEmployee e1 = null, e2 = null, e3 = null, e4 = null, e5 = null, e6 = null;

        try {
            e1 = new CompanyEmployee("Dave", "Smith", "Dsmith@gmail.com", "1969/04/20", "253-555-7894");
            e2 = new CompanyEmployee("Lucy", "Carmon", "LCarmon@gmail.com", "1998/06/05", "253-555-1579");
            e3 = new CompanyEmployee("George", "Jackson", "GJackson@gmail.com", "1979/07/13", "253-555-1264");
            e4 = new CompanyEmployee("Joy", "Vargas", "JVargas@gmail.com", "1984/01/26", "253-555-3645");
            e5 = new CompanyEmployee("Bob", "Velma", "BVelma@gmail.com", "1993/04/15", "253-555-1256");
            e6 = new CompanyEmployee("Sally", "Diego", "SDiego@gmail.com", "1956/09/02", "253-555-5796");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);
        employees.add(e3);
        employees.add(e4);
        employees.add(e5);
        employees.add(e6);
    }

    //Get Methods
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return eMail;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    //Set Methods
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) throws InvalidEmployeeName {
        Matcher matcher = pattern2.matcher(firstName);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
        }
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) throws InvalidEmployeeName {
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern2.matcher(lastName);
        if (matcher1.matches()) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
        }
    }

    public void setEmail(String eMail) throws InvalidEmployeeEmail {
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher(eMail);
        if (matcher2.matches()) {
            this.eMail = eMail;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeEmail("Please use only a valid email addresses");
        }
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthDay) throws InvalidEmployeeBirthday {
        Matcher matcher3 = pattern3.matcher(birthDay);
        if (matcher3.matches()) {
            this.birthDay = birthDay;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeeBirthday("Please only use dates in the format of 'dd/mm/yyyy'");
        }
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) throws InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber {
        Matcher matcher4 = pattern1.matcher(phoneNumber);
        if (matcher4.matches()) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        } else {
            throw new InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber("Please use only use phone #'s in the format of " +
                    "American phone numbers: 123-456-7890");
        }
    }

    //Methods to provide menu operation and search/sort functions
    public static boolean greetingMessage() throws InvalidGreetingChoice, InvalidSortChoice {
        //menu options
        int choice;
        System.out.println("Greetings!  Welcome to the company directory.\nWould you like to " +
                "view a sorted list of existing employees or search for an existing employee?\nPlease" +
                " choose from the following list:\n1.  To print a sorted list.\n2.  To do an employee search.\n" +
                "3.  To create a new employee.\n4.  To exit completely.");

        //menu option based on user input.
        try {
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidGreetingChoice("Please choose only numbers, 1-4.  Try again.");
        }

        //calls each method which handles operations for menu items.  Exit choice turns boolean to false
        //to exit the program.
        if (choice == 1) {
            sortMessage();
        } else if (choice == 2) {
            searchMessage();
        } else if (choice == 3) {
            createMessage();
        } else if (choice == 4) {
            exitMessage();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void sortMessage() throws InvalidSortChoice, InvalidGreetingChoice {
        //menu choice
        int choice1;
        System.out.println("Great, you have chosen to view a sorted list. To proceed, please choose from" +
                " the following list:\n\n1:  First name, ascending\n2:  First name, descending\n3:  Last " +
                "name, ascending\n4:  Last name, descending\n5:  Email, ascending\n6:  Email, descending\n" +
                "7:  Birthday, ascending\n8:  Birthday, descending\n9:  Phone number, ascending\n10: Phone " +
                "number, descending\n11: If you want to exit to the main menu.");

        //menu choice
        try {
            choice1 = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new InvalidSortChoice("Please only enter 1 number, 1-11.  Try again.");
        }

        //exit option calls greetingMessage() to return to main menu.
        if (choice1 == 11) {
            greetingMessage();
        }

        //sort objects by indicated option
        try {
            bubbleSort(employees, choice1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        //print sorted list
        int i = 0;
        for (CompanyEmployee temp : employees) {
            System.out.println("Employee " + ++i + ": " + temp.toString() + "\n");
        }

        //returning to main menu
        System.out.println("Returning you to the main menu.\n");
    }

    public static void searchMessage() throws InvalidSortChoice, InvalidGreetingChoice {
        //Strings for type test and answer
        String type = null, answer;
        //menu int
        int choice2 = 0;

        System.out.println("Great, you have chosen to do a search.\nWhat category do you want to search by?\n1.  " +
                "First name.\n2.  Last Name.\n3.  Email.\n4.  Birthday.\n5.  Phone number.\n6.  Exit Search");

        try {
            choice2 = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        //exit option to return to main menu
        if (choice2 == 6) {
            greetingMessage();
        }

        try {
            type = typeTest(choice2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        //Since search isn't specific, I have a method to indicate what type of search is being performed.
        System.out.println("What " + type + " would you like to search for?\n");

        //take answer, plug it into search method, return the object.toString for the answer, or return
        //message indicating that object doesn't exist.
        try {
            answer = keyboard.nextLine();
            answer = CompanyEmployee.arraySearch(employees, answer, choice2);
            System.out.println(answer);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    public static void createMessage() throws InvalidGreetingChoice, InvalidSortChoice {
        //temp Strings to create employee
        String tempFirst, tempLast, tempEmail, tempBirthday, tempPhone;
        //temp object
        CompanyEmployee newEmployee;
        //int to provide the option to create employee or exit
        int tempChoice;

        System.out.println("Great, you have chosen to create a new employee.\nTo begin, what is the " +
                "employee's first name?");

        tempFirst = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the employee's Last name?");

        tempLast = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the employee's Email?");

        tempEmail = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the employee's Birthday?");

        tempBirthday = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nWhat is the employee's Phone Number?");

        tempPhone = keyboard.nextLine();

        System.out.println("\nOk, You have entered the following information for this employee:\n" +
                "First name:  " + tempFirst + "\nLast name: " + tempLast + "\nEmail:  " + tempEmail + "\nBirthday:" +
                " " + tempBirthday + "\nPhone number: " + tempPhone + "\n\nIf you would like to continue, press " +
                "1, to try again, press 2");

        tempChoice = keyboard.nextInt();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        if (tempChoice == 1) {
            try {
                newEmployee = new CompanyEmployee(tempFirst, tempLast, tempEmail, tempBirthday, tempPhone);
                employees.add(newEmployee);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
            }
            System.out.println("The employee has been created, returning to main menu.\n\n");
        } else if (tempChoice == 2) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen to not create this employee, returning to the main menu.");
        } else {
            if ((tempChoice != 1) && (tempChoice != 2)) {
                System.out.println("Please only use 1 or 2, try again:");
                createMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void exitMessage() {
        System.out.println("You have chosen to exit, thanks for using the Employee Database.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Algorithm for sorting
    public static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<CompanyEmployee> array, int sortType) throws InvalidSortChoice,
            InvalidGreetingChoice {
        // Marks the last element to compare
        int lastPos;
        // Index of an element to compare
        int i;
        // Used to swap to elements
        CompanyEmployee temp;
        //based on the sort chosen, determines output order of method
        int test;
        test = sortType;

        //Firstname Ascending
        if (test == 1) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {
                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getFirstName().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getFirstName()) > 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //FirstName Descending
        else if (test == 2) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getFirstName().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getFirstName()) < 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //LastName Ascending
        else if (test == 3) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getLastName()) > 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //LastName Descending
        else if (test == 4) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getLastName()) < 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Email Ascending
        else if (test == 5) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getEmail().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getEmail()) > 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Email Descending
        else if (test == 6) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getEmail().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getEmail()) < 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Birthday Ascending
        else if (test == 7) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getBirthday().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getBirthday()) > 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Birthday Descending
        else if (test == 8) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getBirthday().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getBirthday()) < 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //PhoneNumber Ascending
        else if (test == 9) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getPhoneNumber().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getPhoneNumber()) > 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //PhoneNumber Descending
        else if (test == 10) {
            for (lastPos = array.size() - 1; lastPos >= 0; lastPos--) {

                for (i = 0; i <= lastPos - 1; i++) {
                    // Compare an element with its neighbor.
                    if (array.get(i).getPhoneNumber().compareTo(array.get(i + 1).getPhoneNumber()) < 0) {
                        // Swap the two elements.
                        temp = array.get(i);
                        array.set(i, array.get(i + 1));
                        array.set(i + 1, temp);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("That's and incorrect choice, please choose a number from 1-11. Try again.");
            sortMessage();
        }
    }

    //Sequential Search algorithm
    public static String arraySearch(ArrayList<CompanyEmployee> array, String searchValue, int searchType) throws
            InvalidGreetingChoice {
        //String used to indicate type of search performed, and return string.
        String type, answer1;

        //typetest returns string matching type of sort requested.
        type = typeTest(searchType);

        for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            //turn object into string for contains check
            answer1 = array.get(i).toString();
            //check if the string contains passed string value of x
            if (answer1.contains(searchValue)) {
                return array.get(i).toString();
            }
        }

        answer1 = ("The search found no employees with the following " + type + ": " + searchValue + "\n");
        return answer1;
    }

    //Method to make sure my output matches user input
    public static String typeTest(int typeTest) {
        //look at value and return string of indicated type
        String typeReturn;

        if (typeTest == 1) {
            typeReturn = "first name";
        } else if (typeTest == 2) {
            typeReturn = "last name";
        } else if (typeTest == 3) {
            typeReturn = "email";
        } else if (typeTest == 4) {
            typeReturn = "birthday";
        } else if (typeTest == 5) {
            typeReturn = "phone Number";
        } else {
            typeReturn = null;
        }
        return typeReturn;
    }

    //custom Exceptions
    public class InvalidEmployeeBirthday extends Exception {
        public InvalidEmployeeBirthday(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public class InvalidEmployeeName extends Exception {
        public InvalidEmployeeName(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public class InvalidEmployeeEmail extends Exception {
        public InvalidEmployeeEmail(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public class InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber extends Exception {
        public InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public static class ObjectEqualsNull extends Exception {
        public ObjectEqualsNull(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public static class InvalidSortChoice extends Exception {
        public InvalidSortChoice(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    public static class InvalidGreetingChoice extends Exception {
        public InvalidGreetingChoice(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
    }

    //MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ObjectEqualsNull, InvalidSortChoice,
            InvalidGreetingChoice, InvalidEmployeeName {

        //Employee objects
        createArray();

        //sentinel while loop to keep the program going till user indicated exit.
        while (greetingMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Single responsibility principle

A class should have a single responsibility. This one does too many things:

- Represents an employee
- Contains a static list of employees
- Handles user input
- Handles various operations (create, search, print)

#### Strange input validation

This constructor is wrong, and pointless:

> ```
> //default constructor, currently unused
> public CompanyEmployee() throws InvalidEmployeeBirthday, InvalidEmployeeEmail, InvalidEmployeeName, InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber {
>     this.firstName = "";
>     this.lastName = "";
>     this.eMail = "";
>     this.birthDay = "1901/01/01";
>     this.phoneNumber = "000-000-0000";
> }
> ```

It's wrong because:

- It declares exceptions to be thrown that it will never throw
- It creates an invalid employee

#### Poor naming and commenting

This kind of code makes two mistakes at once:

> ```
> //Matcher for first name
> Matcher matcher = pattern2.matcher(firstName);
> ```

The variable name `pattern2` is awful,
because it doesn't describe the purpose of the variable.

If you renamed the variable to `firstNameMatcher`,
the comment would become pointless.
In fact, whenever you feel like writing a comment,
consider improving the code in a way to make the comment unnecessary.
It could be renaming a variable,
or moving a block of code to a helper function with a descriptive name.

#### Pointless variables

The `regex`, `regex1`, ..., `regex3` variables are pointless.
They are used only once,
by the corresponding `Pattern` variables.
It would be better to inline these strings in the `Pattern` definitions,
because these variables pollute the namespace of the class.

#### More pointless variables

The constructor creates multiple `Matcher` instances up-front,
even if some of them might never get used,
for example if the first validator fails.
It's best to create a variable right before you need it, not sooner.

In this particular example, the `Matcher` instances seem completely unnecessary, as you could just as well do this:

```
if (firstNameMatcher.matcher(firstName).matches()) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
} else {
    throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
}
```

Even better, no need to assign member fields until everything was validated. So you could write the constructor like this:

```
if (!firstNameMatcher.matcher(firstName).matches()) {
    throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
}

if (!lastNameMatcher.matcher(lastName).matches()) {
    throw new InvalidEmployeeName("Please only use upper and lowercase letters a-Z.");
}

// ...

this.firstName = firstName;
this.lastName = lastName;

// ...
```

#### Too relaxed visibility

The `Pattern` variables are declared with default visibility.
It's a good policy to make everything `private` first,
and relax later when you find a good reason to do that.

#### Code duplication

The validation logic is duplicated in the constructor and the setters.
It would be better to extract that logic to a helper method, for example:

```
private void validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) throws InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber {
    if (!phoneNumberPattern.matcher(phoneNumber).matches()) {
        throw new InvalidEmployeePhoneNumber("Please use only use phone #'s in the format of " +
                "American phone numbers: 123-456-7890");
    }
}
```

You could call this from both the constructor and the setter.